# How do i make the search icon in the SearchView widget to align to the right end of the layout?

Tags: java, android

How do i make the search icon in the SearchView widget to align to the right end of the layout ?
Currently it shows at the leftmost end.[image]

in a main activity xml layout i have

```
  <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
</SearchView>
```

main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchView=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search View");


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), newText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that programmatically in this way

```
SearchView searchView= (SearchView) item.getActionView();
searchView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));
```

or in Xml you need to change the view Hierarchy

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/not"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i was talking about the search icon in the widget